# SelectedItem value of combo box gets empty on updating from viewmodel in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have created a combo box in each datagrid row. The following piece of code is used to create the combo box:

```
<ComboBox Width="166"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridBinding}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Car, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Car, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeader}" />
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Cars}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.GroupedCars, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

The "Car" property for binding "SelectedItem" in combo box is an object of class "Car" holding some properties like id, name, etc.

The problem I am facing is that when I update the value of "Car" property and call "NotifyPropertyChanged" in its setter, then the value of "SelectedItem" in combo box goes blank/empty.

Please suggest.

Comment: You should use SelectedItem **OR** SelectedValue, not both.

Comment: Using "SelectedItem" only, it doesnot update the value on UI when changed from viewmodel. This is because "SelectedItem" compares values to each item of itemsource using reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelectedItem can no longer be found in the Collection (when you update your ItemSource) and gets set to null.

I've simplified your XAML to demonstrate

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Car}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Now the first Item will get selected when you update.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The above approach suggested by ibebbs worked for me in conjunction with using link [https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/]